# Problemas com update em tabela federada

Tags: mysql, table, sql-update

Estou com um problema em entender um erro ao usar uma tabela federada.

Cenário:

> Servidor A: create view federated_view as SELECT ....
>
> Servidor B: create table tabela_federada (A, B, C)
>
> ENGINE=FEDERATED CONNECTION='mysql://user:paswd@:3306/database/federated_view';

Quanto eu realizo um update na tabela_federada, localmente no servidor B, a execução do comando retorna OK, sem erros, mas o valor não é alterado:

```
mysql> update tabela_federada set incidentes_utilizados = 1 where customer_id = 'teste' and incidentes_utilizados = 10;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.17 sec)

mysql> select * from tabela_federada where customer_id = 'teste'\G
incidentes_utilizados: 10
     bugs_qualificados: 3
requisicoes_utilizadas: 2
     horas_disponiveis: 4.00
```

Comment: Fala comitar a atualização; após o update dê um `commit;` e verifique se atualizou o registro;

Comment: Mesmo comitando não deu certo

Answer (score 0):

Você já verificou se os servidores que acessam a base de dados estão com todas as permissões necessárias?

Certifique-se conceder os privilégios necessários sobre os ips que acessam o servidor MySQL:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON nome_da_base_de_dados.* TO 'usuario'@'ip_servidor';
```

Se preferir poderá utilizar "%" ao invés de "ip_servidor" para conceder permissão a todos os ips **(NÃO RECOMENDADO DE FORMA PERMANENTE)**, mas para finalidade de teste definir "%" temporariamente rapidamente pode ser uma boa sugestão, pelo menos pra confirmar se realmente é problema de privilégios (permissão)

Answer (score 0):

Agradeço pela ajuda recebida, localizei a documentação referente a `federated tables` no MySQL, e o que ocorreu foi que a `view` usada para criação da tabela federada possui muitas funções agregadas, como `JOIN` e por isso, não realiza o `update` na tabela de origem, nem na tabela federada.

A saída foi criar uma tabela no servidor A a partir da `view`, e criar a tabela federada a partir desta tabela nova no servidor A.